# no decode delegate for this image format - Imagick - php

Tags: php, image, imagick, resize-image

```
$path=getcwd();
$rawstring = $_POST['img_data'];    
$malestr = str_replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "", $rawstring);
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($malestr);
$img->writeImage($path."/media/import/new.jpg");
```

This is my Imagick functions, I am trying to write an image using base64 encoded data. Its throwing error
.

**"no decode delegate for this image format"**

Comment: `readImageBlob` gets a binary string. decode, at first, content of `$malestr` - use function `base64_decode`

Comment: Thanks Cherry, Please check this question too. stuck up with a pbm.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669087/imagick-unsupported-marker-type-0x68

Comment: Look here and check that original $malestr (before decoding) does not have spaces where + should be https://www.ngxo.com/search/image-upload/62

Comment: Cherry, Is this the answer for my new problem???

Comment: I do not know, check the content of the string before decoding - there should be no spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to manual, `Imagick::readImageBlob` needs a binary string, while you are providing a base64 encoded string to it. Decode the string at first with function `base64_decode` and give the result to `readImageBlob`.

```
// your code above
$malestr = str_replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "", $rawstring);

$malestr = base64_decode($malestr);
if (!$malestr) die('Unable to decode the string');

$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($malestr);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669087/imagick-unsupported-marker-type-0x68 Pleas check this question @Cherry